# Using smart-collections with Meteor 0.7.0.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

When using `SmartCollection` from the `meteor-smart-collections` package with Meteor 0.7.0.1, running Meteor locally does not seem to connect to the local mongodb server started my Meteor. Doesn't Meteor 0.7 start mongod with oplog enabled?

Comment: Meteor 0.7 supersedes `smart-collections`. The oplog tailing is done by meteor.

Comment: @NathanM If I want to use SmartCollection with Meteor 0.7, does it mean I still have to setup my own mongodb server just like before in Meteor 0.6?

Comment: Hmm.. you're on your own there. It looks like meteor starts up a `replSet` even if you're not using oplog tailing. So if you tell `smart-collections` to use `OPLOG_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1/local"`.... you might get lucky.